# How is the MongoDB backup snapshot transferred from Ops Manager to file system store?

Tags: mongodb, ops-manager

I am using Ops Manager for backup and restore.

In docs, it is mentioned that the initial sync between deployment database and Ops manager happens via streaming 10 MB compressed files.
https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/current/core/backup-overview/

however, I am looking for how the snapshot is being transferred from Ops Manager to file system store.

Answer (score 0):

As per MongoDB documentation [here](https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/current/faq/) Ops Manager creates backups of MongoDB replica sets and sharded clusters. After an [initial sync](https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/current/reference/glossary/#term-initial-sync), Ops Manager tails the operation log ([oplog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/)) to provide a continuous backup with point-in-time recovery of replica sets and consistent snapshots of sharded clusters.

**Why doesn’t the Backup feature support standalone deployments?**

After an initial sync of your data, Ops Manager copies data from the [oplog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/) to provide a continuous backup with point-in-time recovery. Ops Manager does not support backup of standalone servers, which do not have an oplog. To support backup with a single [mongod](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#bin.mongod) instance, you can run a one-member replica set.

**How can I use Backup if Backup jobs fail to bind?**

The most common reason that jobs fail to bind to a Backup Daemon is because no daemon has space for a local copy of the backed up replica set.

To increase capacity so that the backup job can bind, you can:

- add an additional backup daemon.
- increase the size of the file system that holds the [Head
  directory](https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/current/reference/configuration/#Head-directory).
- move the Head database data to a new volume with more space, and
  create a symlink or configure the file system mount points so that
  the daemon can access the data using the original path.

Comment: my deployment architecture would have a sharded cluster with 2 shards and data being backed up will be stored in a Storage Area Network (SAN)

Comment: Hello, I am utilizing Ops Manager (4.0.8) for backup and restore. In my case the head database is empty. I am not sure why is this happening ?.